# What's the AngularJS equivalent of a HandlebarsJS "with" block?

Tags: javascript, scope, angularjs, handlebars.js

In [HandlebarsJS](http://handlebarsjs.com/) you can change the scope to a child property of the current scope using a ["with" block](http://handlebarsjs.com/#with). How can I do that in [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  title: "My first post!",
  author: {
    firstName: "Charles",
    lastName: "Jolley"
  }
}
```

just do

```
<span>{{author.firstname}}

{{author.lastName}}</span>
```

AngularJS doesnt care how much your datas are nested.

Comment: Thank you, but my goal is to not need to drill down into the scope for every single proper I want to touch. I specifically want to _change_ the scope. I updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: then it's up to you to write a 'with' directive.